# Work Manager-Web logic

Tags: weblogic, workmanagers

Weblogic Work Manager: There is a requirement to create the work manager to effectively handle the threads. I need to create the WorkManager at domain level. So when I create the workManager at domain level do I need to define the workmanager in web.xml or weblogic.xml , or Just defining in config.xml will work. How the container or the weblogic knows about the custom workmanager created ?

How do we test the same?

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a work manager at the domain level (using the admin console), this modifies config.xml to make it available to all applications. Then in your individual application (weblogic.xml or weblogic-application.xml) you can reference it like:

```
<init-param>
 <param-name>wl-dispatch-policy</param-name>
 <param-value>my_workmanager_name_from_config_xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Thanks. Why at weblogic.xml why not web.xml file. I believe weblogic.xml is at web application level, is that correct.